# Angular 2 - CanActivate undefined value

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the function **CanActivate()** which is the variable **token** does not receive the response of the function verifytoken always returns undefined, how can I solve this problem?

Code

```
private verifytoken()
  {
        if(this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != '' && this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != "undefined")
    {
        this._symfonyservice.validtoken().subscribe(
            data => {this.resut = data;
                      if(this.resut['is_valid']==true)
                      {
                      console.log('true');

                        return true;
                     }
                    else
                    {
                        this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
                        console.log('false');
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                        return false;
                    }
            },
            error =>{
                        alert("Sessão Expirada");
                        this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
                        console.log('false');
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                        return false;
                    }
            );

    }
    else{
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }

  }
  canActivate() {
    let token = this.verifytoken();
    console.log(token);
    return token;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 problems here:

```
private verifytoken()
  {
        if(this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != '' && this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != "undefined")
    {

     // 1 - You are returning nothing here, only inside the subscriptions. So,  you wont be able to get any data if you get inside this if statement
        this._symfonyservice.validtoken().subscribe(
            data => {this.resut = data;
                      if(this.resut['is_valid']==true)
                      {
                      console.log('true');

                        return true;
                     }
                    else
                    {
                        this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
                        console.log('false');
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                        return false;
                    }
            },
            error =>{
                        alert("Sessão Expirada");
                        this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
                        console.log('false');
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                        return false;
                    }
            );

    }
    else{
        // 2 - you are navigating to another place, so you wont be able to get any data from here
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }

  }
  canActivate() {
    let token = this.verifytoken();
    console.log(token);
    return token;
  }
```

So, you have to return the subscriptions inside the if statement or you wont be able to get any data.

--- EDIT ---
Answering the question:

Promisses return promisses, so, you can call subscribe after call the method.

In `verifytoken()` you have to return the promisse and then, in `canActivate()` you have to subscribe to this promisse like I did bellow or wait for the value synchronously:

```
private verifytoken(){
  if(this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != '' && this._functionservice.getCookie("Cookie") != "undefined")
  {
    // here I returned the promisse
    return this._symfonyservice.validtoken().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.resut = data;

        if(this.resut['is_valid']==true){
            console.log('true');
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
            console.log('false');
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }
      },
      error =>{
          alert("Sessão Expirada");
          this._functionservice.deleteCookie("Cookie");
          console.log('false');
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          return false;
      }
    );

  }
  else{
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
  }

}
```

There is a trick here. You cant return the function canActivate() from inside the promisse function because it scope. So, you have 2 options:

1 - (async) is to call the promisse where you are calling canActivate and then whatch for changes from within there.

```
canActivate() {
  return this.verifytoken();
}
```

2 - (sync) is to put a while to detect when the promisse are triggered and the response is assigned to the token variable, so you can return it

```
canActivate() {
  var token = this.verifytoken();


  while(token == undefined){
    // wait until token has been set
  }

  return token;
}
```

Comment: So how can i wait for a response and then return true ?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a idea of how to do this.